# How to implement google search application in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, search

I am new to iPhone development. I am making an application where I need to implement Google Search application and display the results below...

Can anyone please help if there is any tutorial to implement this application. Is there any tutorial?
I think the code given below is right, if so then what else should be added to make it work?

Thank you

```
NSLog(@"%@",searchBarGoogle.text);
NSString *string1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",searchBarGoogle.text];
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com/search?q=%@",string1];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in your .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface eddwedViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UITextField *searchtextField;

}
-(IBAction)search;

@end
```

In your .m file

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
        return YES;
}

-(IBAction)search
{
    NSString *searchString=searchtextField.text;    
    NSString *urlAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com/search?q=%@",searchString];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress]];
}
```

In your view controller.xib make a textfield connect delegate with file owners and outlet with its name.
Make a button and connect it action with search method.

Let me know if it is working for you.

Comment: @gypsa thank u....yup this worked...but when i click button its going to google page and opening...i wan the result to be displayed in same page where i enter the string in textField...below tat itself i want result to be displayed..

Comment: @abhilash ok so wnat you have to do is  create an new view controller and adda web view in it.Lets say you name it webVC.h now  in your -(IBAction)search method navigate to that page and write NSString *searchString=@"apple";    
    NSString *urlAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com/search?q=%@",searchString];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
 code on your viewDidLoad.

Comment: @Abhilash dont hesitate to accept answers and voting up.It will increase your contribution on SO.

Comment: @gypsa thanks a lot..ya sure i ill accept the answer...it helped me a lot.....thank u and if u can clear this doubt as well i ill send u the link

Comment: @gypsa http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6407789/how-to-display-results-from-a-method-in-uilabel

Comment: above answer is bit confusing me...i wan to display in same page but y to hv another viewController class?cant we have webview in same UI below the button?

Comment: @abhilash yes you can have another view below and on that button you can have you view hidden to NO.

Comment: the link you provided is very complicated i dont think you requirement is that.

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088473/how-do-i-url-encode-a-string#answer-8088484

Answer (score 1):

try this:-

```
    NSString *searchString=@"apple";    
    NSString *urlAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com/search?q=%@",searchString];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

It is working fine.Hope It will help you.

what you can do is:-

```
NSString *searchString = searchBarGoogle.text;
```

Comment: thank u...in UI i need to add textfield,webview and searchbar rite?and wat all  other methods i need to implement in code?i am new to iphone i am not so good at coding...if u can help would be much better..

Comment: yes you have to add these  and you have to implement search bar delegate methods and textfield delegate methods.

Comment: i tried following tutorial http://www.totagogo.com/2011/02/08/google-local-search-ios-code/   but its for map application....can we modify this tutorial and implement for search application? which is easier above method or the tutorial?

Comment: can u tell what you exactly want to you.What is your requirement of this page.

Comment: I think you nno need to implement search bar just simply add a tesxfield  and when keyboard button clicked open your google .

Comment: @gypsa ok my requirement is in UI i need to have textfield and a button...when i enter someth like "apple" in the text field and press the button it should search from google and display  minimum 4 results below...so plz  tel me wat all i shd add in UI and give me a code to implement.. i just started with iphone just month a back so i am not so gud at coding part tats the issue...