# How do I URL encode a string

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, nsstring

I have a URL string (`NSString`) with spaces and `&` characters.  How do I url encode the entire string (including the `&` ampersand character and spaces)?

Comment: Check this question - 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21403323/url-encoding-a-string/21404487#21404487

Answer (score 291, accepted):

Unfortunately, `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` doesn't always work 100%.  It encodes non-URL characters but leaves the reserved characters (like slash `/` and ampersand `&`) alone.  Apparently this is a *bug* that Apple is aware of, but since they have not fixed it yet, I have been using this category to url-encode a string:

```
@implementation NSString (NSString_Extended)

- (NSString *)urlencode {
    NSMutableString *output = [NSMutableString string];
    const unsigned char *source = (const unsigned char *)[self UTF8String];
    int sourceLen = strlen((const char *)source);
    for (int i = 0; i < sourceLen; ++i) {
        const unsigned char thisChar = source[i];
        if (thisChar == ' '){
            [output appendString:@"+"];
        } else if (thisChar == '.' || thisChar == '-' || thisChar == '_' || thisChar == '~' || 
                   (thisChar >= 'a' && thisChar <= 'z') ||
                   (thisChar >= 'A' && thisChar <= 'Z') ||
                   (thisChar >= '0' && thisChar <= '9')) {
            [output appendFormat:@"%c", thisChar];
        } else {
            [output appendFormat:@"%%%02X", thisChar];
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Used like this:

```
NSString *urlEncodedString = [@"SOME_URL_GOES_HERE" urlencode];

// Or, with an already existing string:
NSString *someUrlString = @"someURL";
NSString *encodedUrlStr = [someUrlString urlencode];
```

---

This also works:

```
NSString *encodedString = (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
                            NULL,
                            (CFStringRef)unencodedString,
                            NULL,
                            (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
                            kCFStringEncodingUTF8 );
```

---

Some good reading about the subject:

[Objective-c iPhone percent encode a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3423545/836407)
[Objective-C and Swift URL encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8086584/836407)

http://cybersam.com/programming/proper-url-percent-encoding-in-ios
https://devforums.apple.com/message/15674#15674 
http://simonwoodside.com/weblog/2009/4/22/how_to_really_url_encode/

Comment: Why on earth would you use a complicated category like this rather than just dropping down to [CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes()](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFURLRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001206-CH1g-F16659), where you can explicitly specify which characters you want to always escape.

Comment: Yeah, it is common, not to many ways to code it. I probably got it from the new years ago, just now fro my code. That there were two similar questions only hours apart, I suspect it was class homework. :-)

Comment: @KevinBallard because the CF function works on an inclusive model ("escape these characters"), and usually you want to work on an exclusive model ("escape everything *except* these characters")

Comment: @chown [Boy, that category method sure looks familiar!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423545/objective-c-iphone-percent-encode-a-string/3426140#3426140)

Comment: @DaveDeLong That may be where I got it. Its been a standard category in all my projects for a year or so, so I imagine you may have been the original source!  I've edited the wording so it doesnt seem like I am trying to take credit for writing it ).

Comment: How about decoding the encoded character?. Will normal decoding process using NSUTF8StringEncoding give the original string?. Do somebody has idea on that?.

Comment: Why?
   if (thisChar == ' '){
            [output appendString:@"+"];
   }
With out this if it will encode spaces with %20 as I would expect

Comment: `kCFStringEncodingISOLatin1` is more common but anyway it must be set to the encoding configured on the web server. (and yes `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` is better imho)

Comment: @DaveDeLong - Regarding inclusive vs. exclusive: it's worth noting that RFC 3986 required encoding for only the reserved characters (i.e. an inclusive model) and only in a context where they were reserved. This why-not-encoding-everything approach has probably caused more problems than it's solved.

Comment: why it replaces '{space}' for '+' instead of '%20'? I had to change it.

Comment: @aroth: It's only a 6-liner because chown chose to place each parameter on a new line. And I have no issue with a category that wraps `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes()`, my comment was written back when chown only listed the first code snippet in his answer.

Comment: The above not works. It's disturbed original work as well.

Comment: What about russian characters?

Comment: It does not work with wide characters (I.E arabic, chinese...) the first character of the unicode utf-8 multibyte sequence is encoded correcly since > 127, but the following ones are not.

Comment: I've been getting a warning, "implicit conversion loses integer precision: unsigned long to int" on sourceLen, which I've fixed by declaring sourceLen as NSUInteger.

Comment: NSString has a method called stringByRemovingPercentEncoding that should do the trick.

Answer (score 137):

This might be helpful

```
NSString *sampleUrl = @"http://www.google.com/search.jsp?params=Java Developer";
NSString* encodedUrl = [sampleUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:
 NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

For iOS 7+, the recommended way is:

```
NSString* encodedUrl = [sampleUrl stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];
```

You can choose the allowed character set as per the requirement of the URL component.

Comment: This also doesn't correctly encode parameter delimiters like '&', '?' in the case where you are passing content into an API.

Comment: '&' is not a valid character for URL query string parameter. Please try to use '&amp;' instead.

Comment: stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding is DEPRECATED "Use `-stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:` instead, which always uses the recommended UTF-8 encoding, and which encodes for a specific URL component or subcomponent since each URL component or subcomponent has different rules for what characters are valid."

Answer (score 91):

New APIs have been added since the answer was selected; You can now use NSURLUtilities. Since different parts of URLs allow different characters, use the applicable character set. The following example encodes for inclusion in the query string:

```
encodedString = [myString stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet];
```

To specifically convert '&', you'll need to remove it from the url query set or use a different set, as '&' is allowed in a URL query:

```
NSMutableCharacterSet *chars = NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet.mutableCopy;
[chars removeCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange('&', 1)]; // %26
encodedString = [myString stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:chars];
```

Comment: It took me a while to figure out what you meant by "use NSURLUtilities" - but now I see that that is the name of the category of NSString in which Apple defined this new method in iOS 7 and OS X 10.9.

Comment: There is a more elaborate answer like this here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20271177/456366

Comment: Yup. It was also listed as NSURLUtilities in the listing of new APIs released.

Comment: '&' is of course allowed in a query string, so I'll edit my answer using Richard's link.

Comment: `NSMakeRange('&', 1)` doesn't work in Swift, because Swift doesn't allow char to int conversion without hacks.  To use this solution in Swift code, use `removeCharactersInString("&")` instead of `.removeCharactersInRange(...)`

Comment: obh2000, thank you. Since this question is tagged objective-c, the swift edit might not be appropriate. Feel free to find a swift version or create/answer a new question yourself!

Answer (score 17):

Swift 2.0 Example (iOS 9 Compatiable)

```
extension String {

  func stringByURLEncoding() -> String? {

    let characters = NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet().mutableCopy() as! NSMutableCharacterSet

    characters.removeCharactersInString("&")

    guard let encodedString = self.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(characters) else {
      return nil
    }

    return encodedString

  }

}
```

Comment: @AlecThomas you seem to have to jump through a few hoops to get here, thats why its better to hide it away in a extension

Comment: @OliverAtkinson - for me Int(String(Character("&"))) returns nil, as it should.
Instead characters.removeCharactersInString("&").

Answer (score 14):

ios 7 update

```
NSString *encode = [string stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];

NSString *decode = [encode stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: This is inaccurate. You'll want to escape different parts of the URL differently. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423545/objective-c-iphone-percent-encode-a-string/20271177#20271177

Comment: It actually depends on your server for allowed characters, here on my example in the server I was using it only allowed alphanumeric character set, you can change that to specific characters to cater your needs.

Comment: The question asks about encoding the '&' character.

Answer (score 12):

Here's a production-ready flexible approach in **Swift 5.x**:

```swift
public extension CharacterSet {

    static let urlQueryParameterAllowed = CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed.subtracting(CharacterSet(charactersIn: "&?"))

    static let urlQueryDenied           = CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed.inverted()
    static let urlQueryKeyValueDenied   = CharacterSet.urlQueryParameterAllowed.inverted()
    static let urlPathDenied            = CharacterSet.urlPathAllowed.inverted()
    static let urlFragmentDenied        = CharacterSet.urlFragmentAllowed.inverted()
    static let urlHostDenied            = CharacterSet.urlHostAllowed.inverted()

    static let urlDenied                = CharacterSet.urlQueryDenied
        .union(.urlQueryKeyValueDenied)
        .union(.urlPathDenied)
        .union(.urlFragmentDenied)
        .union(.urlHostDenied)


    func inverted() -> CharacterSet {
        var copy = self
        copy.invert()
        return copy
    }
}



public extension String {
    func urlEncoded(denying deniedCharacters: CharacterSet = .urlDenied) -> String? {
        return addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: deniedCharacters.inverted())
    }
}
```

#### Example usage:

```
print("Hello, World!".urlEncoded()!)
print("You&Me?".urlEncoded()!)
print("#Blessed 100%".urlEncoded()!)
print("Pride and Prejudice".urlEncoded(denying: .uppercaseLetters)!)
```

#### Output:

```
Hello,%20World!
You%26Me%3F
%23Blessed%20100%25
%50ride and %50rejudice
```

Comment: Please include a comment explaining the reason for your downvotes so I know how to write a better answer in the future 

Answer (score 8):

I opted to use the `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` call as given by accepted answer, however in newest version of XCode (and IOS), it resulted in an error, so used the following instead:

```
NSString *apiKeyRaw = @"79b|7Qd.jW=])(fv|M&W0O|3CENnrbNh4}2E|-)J*BCjCMrWy%dSfGs#A6N38Fo~";

NSString *apiKey = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL, (CFStringRef)apiKeyRaw, NULL, (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]", kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
```

Comment: It is not encoding space. Example @"string string" and @"string&string" is encoded properly. Please let me know your input on same.

Comment: for me most of the time spent solving this was the denial period where I refused to believe the framework doesnt contain something named similar to 'urlencode' that does this without the messing around..

Answer (score 8):

This code helped me for encoding special characters

```
NSString* encPassword = [password stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet]];
```

Answer (score 6):

Try to use **`stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters`** method with **`[NSCharacterSet URLUserAllowedCharacterSet]`** it will cover all the cases

Objective C

```
NSString *value = @"Test / Test";
value = [value stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLUserAllowedCharacterSet]];
```

swift

```
var value = "Test / Test"
value.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLUserAllowedCharacterSet())
```

Output

**`Test%20%2F%20Test`**

Answer (score 6):

After reading all the answers for this topic and the (**wrong**) accepted one, I want to add my contribution.

**IF** the target is iOS7+, and in 2017 it should since XCode makes really hard to deliver compatibility under iOS8, the best way, thread safe, fast, amd will full UTF-8 support to do this is:

(Objective C code)

```
@implementation NSString (NSString_urlencoding)

- (NSString *)urlencode {
    static NSMutableCharacterSet *chars = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t pred;

    if (chars)
        return [self stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:chars];

    // to be thread safe
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        chars = NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet.mutableCopy;
        [chars removeCharactersInString:@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]"];
    });
    return [self stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:chars];
}
@end
```

This will extend NSString, will exclude RFC forbidden characters, support UTF-8 characters, and let you use things like:

```
NSString *myusername = "I'm[evil]&want(to)break!!!$->àéìòù";
NSLog(@"Source: %@ -> Dest: %@", myusername, [myusername urlencode]);
```

That will print on your debug console:

> Source: I'm[evil]&want(to)break!!!$->àéìòù -> Dest: I%27m%5Bevil%5D%26want%28to%29break%21%21%21%24-%3E%C3%A0%C3%A9%C3%AC%C3%B2%C3%B9

... note also the use of dispatch_once to avoid multiple initializations in multithread environments.

Answer (score 5):

Apple's advice, in the 10.11 release notes, is:

If you need to percent-encode an entire URL string, you can use this code to encode a NSString intended to be a URL (in urlStringToEncode):

```
NSString *percentEncodedURLString =
  [[NSURL URLWithDataRepresentation:[urlStringToEncode dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] relativeToURL:nil] relativeString];
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work, chars like & are still left alone

Comment: This was best answer for me

Answer (score 4):

swift code based on [chown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/836407/chown)'s objc answer in this thread.

```
extension String {
    func urlEncode() -> String {
        return CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
            nil,
            self,
            nil,
            "!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
            CFStringBuiltInEncodings.UTF8.rawValue
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: this function was deprecated in iOS 9 :(

Answer (score 4):

Use NSURLComponents to encode HTTP GET parameters:

```
    var urlComponents = NSURLComponents(string: "https://www.google.de/maps/")!
    urlComponents.queryItems = [
        NSURLQueryItem(name: "q", value: String(51.500833)+","+String(-0.141944)),
        NSURLQueryItem(name: "z", value: String(6))
    ]
    urlComponents.URL     // returns https://www.google.de/maps/?q=51.500833,-0.141944&z=6
```

http://www.ralfebert.de/snippets/ios/encoding-nsurl-get-parameters/

Comment: It does not encode ampersands, slashes or semicolons.

Answer (score 4):

In swift 3:

```
// exclude alpha and numeric == "full" encoding
stringUrl = stringUrl.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .alphanumerics)!;

// exclude hostname and symbols &,/ and etc
stringUrl = stringUrl.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)!;
```

Answer (score 3):

In **Swift 3**, please try out below:

```
let stringURL = "YOUR URL TO BE ENCODE";
let encodedURLString = stringURL.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)
print(encodedURLString)
```

Since, `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` encodes non URL characters but leaves the reserved characters (like `!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]`), You can encode the url like the following code:

```
let stringURL = "YOUR URL TO BE ENCODE";
let characterSetTobeAllowed = (CharacterSet(charactersIn: "!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[] ").inverted)
if let encodedURLString = stringURL.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: characterSetTobeAllowed) {
    print(encodedURLString)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
-(NSString *)encodeUrlString:(NSString *)string {
  return CFBridgingRelease(
                    CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
                        kCFAllocatorDefault,
                        (__bridge CFStringRef)string,
                        NULL,
                        CFSTR("!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]"),
                        kCFStringEncodingUTF8)
                    );
}
```

according to [the following blog](http://isobar.logdown.com/posts/211030-url-encode-decode-in-ios)

Comment: But it's deprecated in iOS 9. What is the updated code for this?

Answer (score 1):

In my case where the last component was Arabic letters I did the following in `Swift 2.2`:

```
extension String {

 func encodeUTF8() -> String? {

    //If I can create an NSURL out of the string nothing is wrong with it
    if let _ = NSURL(string: self) {

        return self
    }

    //Get the last component from the string this will return subSequence
    let optionalLastComponent = self.characters.split { $0 == "/" }.last


    if let lastComponent = optionalLastComponent {

        //Get the string from the sub sequence by mapping the characters to [String] then reduce the array to String
        let lastComponentAsString = lastComponent.map { String($0) }.reduce("", combine: +)


        //Get the range of the last component
        if let rangeOfLastComponent = self.rangeOfString(lastComponentAsString) {
            //Get the string without its last component
            let stringWithoutLastComponent = self.substringToIndex(rangeOfLastComponent.startIndex)


            //Encode the last component
            if let lastComponentEncoded = lastComponentAsString.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.alphanumericCharacterSet()) {


            //Finally append the original string (without its last component) to the encoded part (encoded last component)
            let encodedString = stringWithoutLastComponent + lastComponentEncoded

                //Return the string (original string/encoded string)
                return encodedString
            }
        }
    }

    return nil;
}
}
```

usage:

```
let stringURL = "http://xxx.dev.com/endpoint/nonLatinCharacters"

if let encodedStringURL = stringURL.encodeUTF8() {

    if let url = NSURL(string: encodedStringURL) {

      ...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

So many answers but didn't work for me, so I tried the following:

```
fun simpleServiceCall(for serviceUrl: String, appendToUrl: String) { 
    let urlString: String = serviceUrl + appendToUrl.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlPathAllowed)!     

    let finalUrl = URL(string: urlString)!

    //continue to execute your service call... 
}
```

Hopefully it'll help someone. thanks

Answer (score 0):

For individual www form-encoded query parameters, I made a category on NSString:

```
- (NSString*)WWWFormEncoded{
     NSMutableCharacterSet *chars = NSCharacterSet.alphanumericCharacterSet.mutableCopy;
     [chars addCharactersInString:@" "];
     NSString* encodedString = [self stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:chars];
     encodedString = [encodedString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
     return encodedString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

//This is without test

```
NSMutableCharacterSet* set = [[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] mutableCopy];
[set addCharactersInString:@"-_.~"];
NSString *encode = [test stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:set];
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem passing complex strings as a POST parameter. My strings can contain Asian characters, spaces, quotes and all sorts of special characters. The solution I eventually found was to convert my string into the matching series of unicodes, e.g. "Hu0040Hu0020Hu03f5...." using [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hu%04x",[string characterAtIndex:i]] to get the Unicode from each character in the original string. The same can be done in Java.

This string can be safely passed as a POST parameter.

On the server side (PHP), I change all the "H" to "\" and I pass the resulting string to json_decode. Final step is to escape single quotes before storing the string into MySQL.

This way I can store any UTF8 string on my server.

Answer (score 0):

This one is working for me.

```
func stringByAddingPercentEncodingForFormData(plusForSpace: Bool=false) -> String? {
    let unreserved = "*-._"
    let allowed = NSMutableCharacterSet.alphanumericCharacterSet()
    allowed.addCharactersInString(unreserved)

    if plusForSpace {
        allowed.addCharactersInString(" ")
    }

    var encoded = stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(allowed)
    if plusForSpace {
        encoded = encoded?.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ",
                                                                withString: "+")
    }
    return encoded
}
```

I found the above function from this link: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/how-to-percent-encode-a-url-string/

You can also use this function with swift extension. Please let me know if there is any issue.

Answer (score 0):

For the php function urlencode encoding a NSString to a cString with UTF8Encode, like [NSString UTF8String] was not working.

Here is my custom objective c NSString+ASCIIencode Category with works with all ASCII values 0..255

Header

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface NSString (ASCIIEncode)

- (const char*)ASCIIEncode;

@end
```

Implementation

```
#import "NSString+ASCIIEncode.h"

@implementation NSString (ASCIIEncode)

- (const char*)ASCIIEncode {
    
    static char output[1024];
    
    // https://tools.piex.at/ascii-tabelle/
    // https://www.ionos.de/digitalguide/server/knowhow/ascii-american-standard-code-for-information-interchange/
    
    NSMutableArray *ascii = [NSMutableArray new];
// Hex
// 000                          Dez Hex
    [ascii addObject:@"\0"]; // 000 000 NUL
    [ascii addObject:@( 1)]; // 001 001 SOH
    [ascii addObject:@( 2)]; // 002 002 STX
    [ascii addObject:@( 3)]; // 003 003 ETX
    [ascii addObject:@( 4)]; // 004 004 EOT
    [ascii addObject:@( 5)]; // 005 005 ENQ
    [ascii addObject:@( 6)]; // 006 006 ACK
    [ascii addObject:@"\a"]; // 007 007 BEL
    [ascii addObject:@"\b"]; // 008 008 BS
    [ascii addObject:@( 9)]; // 009 009 TAB
    [ascii addObject:@"\n"]; // 010 00A LF
    [ascii addObject:@(11)]; // 011 00B VT
    [ascii addObject:@(12)]; // 012 00C FF
    [ascii addObject:@"\r"]; // 013 00D CR
    [ascii addObject:@(14)]; // 014 00E SO
    [ascii addObject:@(15)]; // 015 00F NAK
// 010
    [ascii addObject:@(16)]; // 016 010 DLE
    [ascii addObject:@(17)]; // 017 011 DC1
    [ascii addObject:@(18)]; // 018 012 DC2
    [ascii addObject:@(19)]; // 019 013 DC3
    [ascii addObject:@(20)]; // 020 014 DC4
    [ascii addObject:@(21)]; // 021 015 NAK
    [ascii addObject:@(22)]; // 022 016 SYN
    [ascii addObject:@(23)]; // 023 017 ETB
    [ascii addObject:@(24)]; // 024 018 CAN
    [ascii addObject:@(25)]; // 025 019 EM
    [ascii addObject:@(26)]; // 026 01A SUB
    [ascii addObject:@(27)]; // 027 01B ESC
    [ascii addObject:@(28)]; // 028 01C FS
    [ascii addObject:@(29)]; // 029 01D GS
    [ascii addObject:@(30)]; // 030 01E RS
    [ascii addObject:@(31)]; // 031 01F US
// 020
    [ascii addObject:@" "];  // 032 020 Space
    [ascii addObject:@"!"];  // 033 021
    [ascii addObject:@"\""]; // 034 022
    [ascii addObject:@"#"];  // 035 023
    [ascii addObject:@"$"];  // 036 024
    [ascii addObject:@"%"];  // 037 025
    [ascii addObject:@"&"];  // 038 026
    [ascii addObject:@"'"];  // 039 027
    [ascii addObject:@"("];  // 040 028
    [ascii addObject:@")"];  // 041 029
    [ascii addObject:@"*"];  // 042 02A
    [ascii addObject:@"+"];  // 043 02B
    [ascii addObject:@","];  // 044 02C
    [ascii addObject:@"-"];  // 045 02D
    [ascii addObject:@"."];  // 046 02E
    [ascii addObject:@"/"];  // 047 02F
// 030
    [ascii addObject:@"0"];  // 048 030
    [ascii addObject:@"1"];  // 049 031
    [ascii addObject:@"2"];  // 050 032
    [ascii addObject:@"3"];  // 051 033
    [ascii addObject:@"4"];  // 052 034
    [ascii addObject:@"5"];  // 053 035
    [ascii addObject:@"6"];  // 054 036
    [ascii addObject:@"7"];  // 055 037
    [ascii addObject:@"8"];  // 056 038
    [ascii addObject:@"9"];  // 057 039
    [ascii addObject:@":"];  // 058 03A
    [ascii addObject:@";"];  // 059 03B
    [ascii addObject:@"<"];  // 060 03C
    [ascii addObject:@"="];  // 061 03D
    [ascii addObject:@">"];  // 062 03E
    [ascii addObject:@"?"];  // 063 03F
// 040
    [ascii addObject:@"@"];  // 064 040
    [ascii addObject:@"A"];  // 065 041
    [ascii addObject:@"B"];  // 066 042
    [ascii addObject:@"C"];  // 067 043
    [ascii addObject:@"D"];  // 068 044
    [ascii addObject:@"E"];  // 069 045
    [ascii addObject:@"F"];  // 070 046
    [ascii addObject:@"G"];  // 071 047
    [ascii addObject:@"H"];  // 072 048
    [ascii addObject:@"I"];  // 073 049
    [ascii addObject:@"J"];  // 074 04A
    [ascii addObject:@"K"];  // 075 04B
    [ascii addObject:@"L"];  // 076 04C
    [ascii addObject:@"M"];  // 077 04D
    [ascii addObject:@"N"];  // 078 04E
    [ascii addObject:@"O"];  // 079 04F
// 050
    [ascii addObject:@"P"];  // 080 050
    [ascii addObject:@"Q"];  // 081 051
    [ascii addObject:@"R"];  // 082 052
    [ascii addObject:@"S"];  // 083 053
    [ascii addObject:@"T"];  // 084 054
    [ascii addObject:@"U"];  // 085 055
    [ascii addObject:@"V"];  // 086 056
    [ascii addObject:@"W"];  // 087 057
    [ascii addObject:@"X"];  // 088 058
    [ascii addObject:@"Y"];  // 089 059
    [ascii addObject:@"Z"];  // 090 05A
    [ascii addObject:@"["];  // 091 05B
    [ascii addObject:@"\\"]; // 092 05C
    [ascii addObject:@"]"];  // 093 05D
    [ascii addObject:@"^"];  // 094 05E
    [ascii addObject:@"_"];  // 095 05F
// 060
    [ascii addObject:@"`"];  // 096 060
    [ascii addObject:@"a"];  // 097 061
    [ascii addObject:@"b"];  // 098 062
    [ascii addObject:@"c"];  // 099 063
    [ascii addObject:@"d"];  // 100 064
    [ascii addObject:@"e"];  // 101 065
    [ascii addObject:@"f"];  // 102 066
    [ascii addObject:@"g"];  // 103 067
    [ascii addObject:@"h"];  // 104 068
    [ascii addObject:@"i"];  // 105 069
    [ascii addObject:@"j"];  // 106 06A
    [ascii addObject:@"k"];  // 107 06B
    [ascii addObject:@"l"];  // 108 06C
    [ascii addObject:@"m"];  // 109 06D
    [ascii addObject:@"n"];  // 110 06E
    [ascii addObject:@"o"];  // 111 06F
// 070
    [ascii addObject:@"p"];  // 112 070
    [ascii addObject:@"q"];  // 113 071
    [ascii addObject:@"r"];  // 114 072
    [ascii addObject:@"s"];  // 115 073
    [ascii addObject:@"t"];  // 116 074
    [ascii addObject:@"u"];  // 117 075
    [ascii addObject:@"v"];  // 118 076
    [ascii addObject:@"w"];  // 119 077
    [ascii addObject:@"x"];  // 120 078
    [ascii addObject:@"y"];  // 121 079
    [ascii addObject:@"z"];  // 122 07A
    [ascii addObject:@"{"];  // 123 07B
    [ascii addObject:@"|"];  // 124 07C
    [ascii addObject:@"}"];  // 125 07D
    [ascii addObject:@"~"];  // 126 07E
    [ascii addObject:@(127)];// 127 07F DEL
// 080
    [ascii addObject:@"€"];  // 128 080
    [ascii addObject:@(129)];// 129 081
    [ascii addObject:@"‚"];  // 130 082
    [ascii addObject:@"ƒ"];  // 131 083
    [ascii addObject:@"„"];  // 132 084
    [ascii addObject:@"…"];  // 133 085
    [ascii addObject:@"†"];  // 134 086
    [ascii addObject:@"‡"];  // 135 087
    [ascii addObject:@"ˆ"];  // 136 088
    [ascii addObject:@"‰"];  // 137 089
    [ascii addObject:@"Š"];  // 138 08A
    [ascii addObject:@"‹"];  // 139 08B
    [ascii addObject:@"Œ"];  // 140 08C
    [ascii addObject:@(141)];// 141 08D
    [ascii addObject:@"Ž"];  // 142 08E
    [ascii addObject:@(143)];  // 143 08F
// 090
    [ascii addObject:@(144)];// 144 090
    [ascii addObject:@"‘"];  // 145 091
    [ascii addObject:@"’"];  // 146 092
    [ascii addObject:@"“"];  // 147 093
    [ascii addObject:@"”"];  // 148 094
    [ascii addObject:@"•"];  // 149 095
    [ascii addObject:@"–"];  // 150 096
    [ascii addObject:@"—"];  // 151 097
    [ascii addObject:@"˜"];  // 152 098
    [ascii addObject:@"™"];  // 153 099
    [ascii addObject:@"š"];  // 154 09A
    [ascii addObject:@"›"];  // 155 09B
    [ascii addObject:@"œ"];  // 156 09C
    [ascii addObject:@(157)];// 157 09D
    [ascii addObject:@"ž"];  // 158 09E
    [ascii addObject:@"Ÿ"];  // 159 09F
// 0A0
    [ascii addObject:@(160)];// 160 0A0
    [ascii addObject:@"¡"];  // 161 0A1
    [ascii addObject:@"¢"];  // 162 0A2
    [ascii addObject:@"£"];  // 163 0A3
    [ascii addObject:@"¤"];  // 164 0A4
    [ascii addObject:@"¥"];  // 165 0A5
    [ascii addObject:@"¦"];  // 166 0A6
    [ascii addObject:@"§"];  // 167 0A7
    [ascii addObject:@"¨"];  // 168 0A8
    [ascii addObject:@"©"];  // 169 0A9
    [ascii addObject:@"ª"];  // 170 0AA
    [ascii addObject:@"«"];  // 171 0AB
    [ascii addObject:@"¬"];  // 172 0AC
    [ascii addObject:@(173)];// 173 0AD
    [ascii addObject:@"®"];  // 174 0AE
    [ascii addObject:@"¯"];  // 175 0AF
// 0B0
    [ascii addObject:@"°"];  // 176 0B0
    [ascii addObject:@"±"];  // 177 0B1
    [ascii addObject:@"²"];  // 178 0B2
    [ascii addObject:@"³"];  // 179 0B3
    [ascii addObject:@"´"];  // 180 0B4
    [ascii addObject:@"µ"];  // 181 0B5
    [ascii addObject:@"¶"];  // 182 0B6
    [ascii addObject:@"·"];  // 183 0B7
    [ascii addObject:@"¸"];  // 184 0B8
    [ascii addObject:@"¹"];  // 185 0B9
    [ascii addObject:@"º"];  // 186 0BA
    [ascii addObject:@"»"];  // 187 0BB
    [ascii addObject:@"¼"];  // 188 0BC
    [ascii addObject:@"½"];  // 189 0BD
    [ascii addObject:@"¾"];  // 190 0BE
    [ascii addObject:@"¿"];  // 191 0BF
// 0C0
    [ascii addObject:@"À"];  // 192 0C0
    [ascii addObject:@"Á"];  // 193 0C1
    [ascii addObject:@"Â"];  // 194 0C2
    [ascii addObject:@"Ã"];  // 195 0C3
    [ascii addObject:@"Ä"];  // 196 0C4
    [ascii addObject:@"Å"];  // 197 0C5
    [ascii addObject:@"Æ"];  // 198 0C6
    [ascii addObject:@"Ç"];  // 199 0C7
    [ascii addObject:@"È"];  // 200 0C8
    [ascii addObject:@"É"];  // 201 0C9
    [ascii addObject:@"Ê"];  // 202 0CA
    [ascii addObject:@"Ë"];  // 203 0CB
    [ascii addObject:@"Ì"];  // 204 0CC
    [ascii addObject:@"Í"];  // 205 0CD
    [ascii addObject:@"Î"];  // 206 0CE
    [ascii addObject:@"Ï"];  // 207 0CF
// 0D0
    [ascii addObject:@"Ð"];  // 208 0D0
    [ascii addObject:@"Ñ"];  // 209 0D1
    [ascii addObject:@"Ò"];  // 210 0D2
    [ascii addObject:@"Ó"];  // 211 0D3
    [ascii addObject:@"Ô"];  // 212 0D4
    [ascii addObject:@"Õ"];  // 213 0D5
    [ascii addObject:@"Ö"];  // 214 0D6
    [ascii addObject:@"×"];  // 215 0D7
    [ascii addObject:@"Ø"];  // 216 0D8
    [ascii addObject:@"Ù"];  // 217 0D9
    [ascii addObject:@"Ú"];  // 218 0DA
    [ascii addObject:@"Û"];  // 219 0DB
    [ascii addObject:@"Ü"];  // 220 0DC
    [ascii addObject:@"Ý"];  // 221 0DD
    [ascii addObject:@"Þ"];  // 222 0DE
    [ascii addObject:@"ß"];  // 223 0DF
// 0E0
    [ascii addObject:@"à"];  // 224 0E0
    [ascii addObject:@"á"];  // 225 0E1
    [ascii addObject:@"â"];  // 226 0E2
    [ascii addObject:@"ã"];  // 227 0E3
    [ascii addObject:@"ä"];  // 228 0E4
    [ascii addObject:@"å"];  // 229 0E5
    [ascii addObject:@"æ"];  // 230 0E6
    [ascii addObject:@"ç"];  // 231 0E7
    [ascii addObject:@"è"];  // 232 0E8
    [ascii addObject:@"é"];  // 233 0E9
    [ascii addObject:@"ê"];  // 234 0EA
    [ascii addObject:@"ë"];  // 235 0EB
    [ascii addObject:@"ì"];  // 236 0EC
    [ascii addObject:@"í"];  // 237 0ED
    [ascii addObject:@"î"];  // 238 0EE
    [ascii addObject:@"ï"];  // 239 0EF
// 0F0
    [ascii addObject:@"ð"];  // 240 0F0
    [ascii addObject:@"ñ"];  // 241 0F1
    [ascii addObject:@"ò"];  // 242 0F2
    [ascii addObject:@"ó"];  // 243 0F3
    [ascii addObject:@"ô"];  // 244 0F4
    [ascii addObject:@"õ"];  // 245 0F5
    [ascii addObject:@"ö"];  // 246 0F6
    [ascii addObject:@"÷"];  // 247 0F7
    [ascii addObject:@"ø"];  // 248 0F8
    [ascii addObject:@"ù"];  // 249 0F9
    [ascii addObject:@"ú"];  // 250 0FA
    [ascii addObject:@"û"];  // 251 0FB
    [ascii addObject:@"ü"];  // 252 0FC
    [ascii addObject:@"ý"];  // 253 0FD
    [ascii addObject:@"þ"];  // 254 0FE
    [ascii addObject:@"ÿ"];  // 255 0FF
    
    NSInteger i;
    
    for (i=0; i < self.length; i++) {
        
        NSRange range;
        range.location = i;
        range.length = 1;
        
        NSString *charString = [self substringWithRange:range];
        
        for (NSInteger asciiIdx=0; asciiIdx < ascii.count; asciiIdx++) {
            
            if ([charString isEqualToString:ascii[asciiIdx]]) {
                unsigned char c = (unsigned char)asciiIdx;
                output[i] = c;
                break;
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    // Don't forget string termination
    output[i] = 0;

    return (const char*)&output[0];
}

@end
```

Comment: how to use this example

Answer (score 0):

> This is what I did using Swift 5:

```
func formatPassword() -> String {
    
    var output = "";

    for ch in self {

        let char = String(ch)

        switch ch {

            case " ":
                output.append("+")

                break

            case ".", "-", "_", "~", "a"..."z", "A"..."Z", "0"..."9":

                output.append(char)

                break

                default:

                print(ch)

                let unicode = char.unicodeScalars.first?.value ?? 0

                let unicodeValue = NSNumber(value: unicode).intValue

                let hexValue = String(format: "%02X", arguments: [unicodeValue])

                output = output.appendingFormat("%%%@", hexValue)

                }

            }
    
    return output as String
}
```

> Then I called this function where I defined my password.