# iPhone NSURL error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, nsurl

I'm using this code to assign the link of my button to the wiki page, while capturing the countryName.text in the UILabel to be a part of the URL, but Xcode gives me an error when I press it. Here's the code:

```
- (IBAction)openWiki:(id)sender {
NSString *sampleUrl = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%@%@",self.countryName.text];
NSURL *wikiUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:sampleUrl];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:wikiUrl];}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the error you are getting on XCODE?

Comment: Get rid of one of the %@ symbols.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your format you expect two parameters, but give only one:

```
@"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%@%@",self.countryName.text
//                             ^^
```

Remove one specifier:

```
- (IBAction)openWiki:(id)sender {
    NSString *sampleUrl = [[NSString alloc] 
        initWithFormat:@"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%@",self.countryName.text];
    //                                                ^^
    NSURL *wikiUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:sampleUrl];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:wikiUrl];
}
```

Comment: This helped, but when self.countryName.text is something like "San Marino" (two words instead of one) the link wouldn't open :(

Comment: That doesn't matter, it handles a full NSString. You might what to encode it before, but that's something else.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088473/url-encode-a-nsstring