# How can I send strings with whitespaces by AFNetworking client?

Tags: ios, afnetworking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [URL encode a NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088473/url-encode-a-nsstring)

I am trying to send strings with whitespaces like:

```
stack exchange
```

by

```
[[ApiClient sharedClient] getPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/search/?q=%@", @"stack exchange"] parameters:nil success:^ ...
```

But I am getting

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1000 "bad URL"
```

How can I solde this?

Comment: You need to URL encode the string ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088473/url-encode-a-nsstring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to want to encode your url parameters.

```
// Add this to your class or universal class to be used
// Encode a string to embed in an URL.
NSString *encodeToPercentEscapeString(NSString *string) {
    return (__bridge NSString *)
    CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
                                            (CFStringRef) string,
                                            NULL,
                                            (CFStringRef) @"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
                                            kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
}

// now you can encode your parameters before adding to your url
NSString *urlParam = @"My custom text";

urlParam = encodeToPerecentEscapeString(urlParam);

// now you can use urlParam in any url parameter requirement
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a sample project a while ago that shows the different ways you can escape strings in ObjC. It's [on github](https://github.com/Keithbsmiley/NSStringEscapeTest/blob/master/StringEscapeTest/KSAppDelegate.m)

I ended up using something like this:

```
NSString *escapedString = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge CFStringRef) myString, NULL, CFSTR("!*()$&`:<>[]{}\"+#@/;=?\\^|~'%%,."), kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
```

This seemed to cover all the edge cases I could find.