# How to Pass JSON NSString containing JSON to a Javascript Method from an Objective C method

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, ios, json

I have a requirement where the `objective C code should` consume the `WebService` and the response received in `JSON format` has to be passed as an argument to a `javascript` method for further processing.I am using `UIWebView` which will display the appropriate results after processing `JSON response.`
The issue arises when i try to pass the JSON string to `Javascript` method.Javascript method does not simply accept the input.

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[resultData bytes] length:[resultData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@",responseString);
    [self returnResponseToJavaScriptMethods:responseString];
}


-(void)returnResponseToJavaScriptMethods:(NSString*)theResponse{
    [viewMainWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"retrieveServerResponse('%@')",theResponse]];
}
```

Is there anything that I am missing out ?? Simple strings are getting passed properly using the same approach.

**UPDATE** : 
Encoding the `responseData` to `UTF8StringEncoding` did the trick.

```
[theResponse stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to URL-escape the JSON string before posting it to the javascript.

Try to change:

```
-(void)returnResponseToJavaScriptMethods:(NSString*)theResponse{
  [viewMainWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"retrieveServerResponse('%@')",theResponse]];
}
```

to

```
-(void)returnResponseToJavaScriptMethods:(NSString*)theResponse{
  [viewMainWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"retrieveServerResponse('%@')",
 [theResponse stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];
}
```

And see if that helps you. Note, however, that there are better (or more surefire) ways to escape a string, for example the one given at this answer: [How do I URL encode a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088473/url-encode-a-nsstring)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion.It worked like a charm.But now the string which we padded with escape characters needs to be cleaned up to be converted as a proper JSON response.That is giving me another headache.Please do mention in comments if you know a way to perfectly reverse the encoding in javascript.

Comment: I don't know if it's "perfect", but have you tried the `unescape()` function? It should work, just `unescape(your_escaped_json_string)`

Comment: I changed my encoding approach.I just encode/decode it using Base64 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for a `retrieveServerResponse()` in javascript, just use `unescape(percentEscapedStringFromiOS)` after you percent-escaped the string in iOS

```
NSString *encodedString = [string stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
// CAVEAT: unescape(\"%@\") is important since "'" (single quote) isn't excaped by the above function!
NSString *jsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myJSstring = unescape(\"%@\")", encodedString]];

NSString *jsResult = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
```