# NSString from webview with JSON string

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, objective-c, webview

I have a webview from which I'm calling a method that returns result of `JSON.stringify();`
Then it is stored in database and used later to restore state of the page in webview.

```
NSString *data = [self.browser stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"course.serialize();"];
[self.course storeRawSerializedData:data];
```

when it is retrieved from database (Core Data) I'm injecting it into loaded html page source like so:

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    if(_data){
        NSString* content = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:_data
                                                  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        _data = nil;
        _jsReady = YES;

        NSString *data = @"";
        if(self.course.returnRawSerializedData){
            data = [data stringByAppendingString:@"<script type=\"text/javascript\">var restoreData=%@;</script>"];
            data = [NSString stringWithFormat:data, self.course.returnRawSerializedData];
        }
        //inject extra content to the page
        content = [data stringByAppendingString:content];
        //load modified HTML string
        [self.browser loadHTMLString:content baseURL:_url];
    }
}
```

The problem is with JSON being invalid after this trip:

the json returned by webview is:

`{"status":"incomplete","data_json":"{\"colour\":\"#000000\"}"}`

and after injecting it looks like this:

`<script type=\"text/javascript\">var restoreData={"status":"incomplete","data_json":"{\"colour\":\"#000000\"}"};</script>`

The page returns the `SyntaxError: JSON parse error: Unexpected identifier "object"`

When I wrap it with single or double quotes in stringByAppendingString method then page returns the `SyntaxError: JSON parse error: Expected '}'`

It works when I escape all double quotes (manually) but I don;t know how to do it programatically, I expected that string returned from stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString will be already escaped to be used within double quotes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14198331/how-to-pass-json-nsstring-containing-json-to-a-javascript-method-from-an-objecti

Comment: It is not and proposed solution within the given SO question doesnt fix my problem (and how could it when it escapes to percent encoded and I need escaped quotes!).

Comment: I use the solution proposed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/770533/923340) which is not ideal as it means that my serialize method will do escaping. However it would be better if I could have a objective-c based solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also consider following as solution,

you `Base64` encode `NSString` that you want to inject in `Objective-C` do the reverse in `Javascript`.

Comment: This is variation of the solution that I've used now (see my comment with link to source) and it is not ideal solution, this time I have control over the JS and I can modify returned value or in this case injected value but it may not be always possible. I expected that there is built in solution or at least some methods that will do it for me.

Comment: I'm accepting this as anyway this is how I'm doing this now, but shame that there is no built in solution.

Answer (score 0):

Escape quotes will work.

For example:

```
content = [content stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\\\""];
```