# How to adapte a NSString with a NSUrl parameter?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

As you know no `URL` contain a space between the word of there parameters
and I want to pass  `MyString=@"hello every body"` to my `URL` parameters, like this

```
[@"http://www.site.com/index.php?contenu=" stringByAppendingString:MyString];
```

And I don't know how I can convert MyString to a valid format for URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try with Following Code :**

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.site.com/index.php?contenu=%@", MyString];
NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

[AlsoRead This Official Documentation about String Format Specifiers.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do the whole thing in this manner ?

First make a string with parameter in the following way :

```
NSString *stringURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.site.com/index.php?contenu=%@",MyString];
```

Convert the string to URL :

`NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:MyString];`

Now you can use that url safely.

Answer (score 0):

for space u should use %20, for that use url encode
[Try This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088473/url-encode-a-nsstring)

Or use stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding

Answer (score 0):

try like this ,

```
NSString *encodedUrlString = [urlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this by replacing space with **%20**

Code ::

```
NSString *reqString;
reqString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s%@", Server_URL, your_paramater];
reqString = [reqString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
NSLog(@"... URL :::: %@", reqString);
```

Try it once, It may be help you.

Thanks.