# twitter rest api - post a status with a user mention

Tags: ios, twitter

Using twitter's rest api, and specifcally the method :

```
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/update
```

I'm trying to post a tweet that will include a user mention ( @[screenname] ).
However, it seems as though twitter won't allow me to post any @ sign unless I encode it.
I've tried several encoding techniques, but non seem to provide me with the suitable encoding twitter is looking for.

As to the question, What should "@" be substitute with so twitter will allow me to pass the message correctly? I'm posting the command via an iphone app, and from several reasons I cannot use either ios 6 new social integration, nor twitter's api wrapper for ios.

Edit: 
The encoding techniques I've tried -

- stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
- [How do I URL encode a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088473/url-encode-a-nsstring)

Thank you

Comment: Which encoding techniques have you tried unsuccessfully? What results did you see?

Answer (score 0):

As it seems I had to specifically percent encode the @ using the following method:

```
bodyString = [bodyString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"@" withString:@"%40"];
```

Hope it will help someone in the future.