# Json web service https

Tags: iphone, ios, web-services, https

Could you help me, with a example, where i consume a json webservice in a https url.
i have tried:
where urlConParametros is a https url.

```
NSString* encriptado = nil;
NSString* urlConParametros = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@?%@=%@", URL, metodo, key, valorSinEcncriptar];
NSError* error;
if(encriptado == nil){
    NSMutableURLRequest *getRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlConParametros]];
    [getRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    NSError *requestError;
    NSURLResponse *urlResponse = nil;
    NSData *response1 =[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:getRequest returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&requestError];
    NSString* data = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlConParametros] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                           error:&error];
    return data;
}
```

but return data nil. 
My problem is that with http, the same web service response the correct data, but when it doing with https, the response is nil.

Comment: How can this Question be related to Xcode ?

Comment: My first guess would be parameter encoding.  Is there a simpler endpoint in the web service that doesn't take parameters?  Start with that and see if you can make a simple get work.  Then look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088473/url-encode-an-nsstring.  Also, consider changing to asynchronous once you get this working.

Comment: Sorry, it's not Xcode, its IOS question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add some more details in the Question about What you want exactly, What you have tried and What are the Problems you are facing while implementation ?

If you want to `GET` some data from the **Web Service** , you can get it like this. :

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlConParametros]];
NSString *respStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"My Response :: %@",respStr);
```

If the **Response** is in `JSON Format` then you should do something like this :

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlConParametros]];
NSError* error;
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSLog(@"My Response :: %@",json);
```

Take a look at the **Sample Code** for [`AdvancedURLConnections`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AdvancedURLConnections/Introduction/Intro.html).

Comment: I would like, consume json in a https url.

Comment: @user2587694 : What does that mean ? Explain properly.

Comment: well, when the request is to https, a certified is responsed, in a first time, and the response is not data. how can i get the data.

Comment: i have used the code above, and json var is nil with https. if i use http url, it's works, but not https, and in a browser the response it's ok, with http and https

Comment: Can anybody help me get json from https url?

Comment: @user2587694 : Have you checked it using first way (using `respStr`) that i have described ?

Comment: Excuseme, i had test with http, not https, with https respStr.length is 0.

Comment: @user2587694 : For `https` , take a look at the link I added in my Answer.