# response not coming with initWithContentsOfURL

Tags: iphone

I have an url i am executing,
The encoded url is like,
http://admin:testsite@www.arabcircleonline.com/index.php?do=%2Fwebservice%2Fwhisper%2Flogin_chauhankevalp%40gmail.com%2Fpassword_keval%2Faction_whisper%2Fwhisperdata_%7B%22user_status%22%3A%22test123%22%2C%22privacy%22%3A0%2C%22privacy_comment%22%3A0%7D

When i execute it with NSURLConnection or initWithContentsOfURL both are not giving the response expected.

how this should be executed?

This url is protected with username and password.. is there any concern with this?.. I am using the authentication to make the URL work on server

Help will be appreciated..

Comment: Can you share some code?  Specifically at the point at which you create/start your NSURLConnection.

Comment: I have created the connection like                            NSString *final=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://admin:testsite@www.arabcircleonline.com/index.php?%@",params];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:final]];
        
        // Create url connection and fire request
        NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];  I have encoded the parameters in param and i am checking the response in connectionDidFinishLoading method

Comment: Please add the (relevant) code to your question. It is unreadable in a comment.

Comment: NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:final]];
        
        NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];