# Song doesn't play when method called from another class

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer

I'm trying to play a song in my application. When the the code to play a song is put right away in the controller it runs good. 
 
But when i put the code in a class, call the class then call the method to play the song, nothing happens ? If someone have a clue please feel free to help.

here is the code to play a song

```
-(void)randomSound{
    NSLog(@"sound");
    NSString * path;

    NSError * err;
    NSString *name;
    NSArray *names = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1up.wav", @"mario02.dsp.wav", @"mario04.dsp.wav", @"mario06.dsp.wav", @"mrf.dsp.wav",  nil];
    name = [names randomObject];
    path = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:name];
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
        NSURL * url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
        self.snd = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url
                                                          error:&err] ;
        if (! self.snd) {
            NSLog(@"data named '%@' had error %@", name, [err localizedDescription]);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"playing");
            [self.snd prepareToPlay];
            [self.snd play];
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"data file '%@' doesn't exist at '%@'", name, path);
    }
}
```

The way i call the method

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"YAHOO"])
{
    YahooViewController *YH = [[YahooViewController alloc] init];
    [YH randomSound];
}
```

The random method in case someone would like to know whats in it

```
-(id)randomObject {
    NSUInteger myCount = [self count];
    if (myCount)
        return [self objectAtIndex:arc4random_uniform(myCount)];
    else
        return nil;
}
```

Comment: You have NSlog's in this function, what is in the console when you run this ?

Comment: sound and playing NSLogs are displayed in the console, so i presume it is going trough the whole method.

Comment: You can't assume everything is working fine, Here you are given an NSError object to tell you if you have any issues with setting this up: self.snd = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&err];  You need to use this object to catch errors. Check is there anything in here

Comment: I printed it, it gave me this : <AVAudioPlayer: 0xbf6adf0> wich i think is were my song is kept in the memory. Also i have :  error (null).

Comment: Not the AVAudioPlayer instance the NSError instance. Your passing a reference by using '&err'. Print 'err'. Your only checking if the audio player is empty, if its empty then you print the error reason. There are MANY other reasons for it to not work that would not return empty but would give you an error. You need to check if both are null before continuing

Comment: Is this print good NSLog(@"snd = '%@' had error = %@", self.snd, [err localizedDescription]); ?      Response is : snd = '<AVAudioPlayer: 0xce252b0>' had error = (null)

Comment: Yes thats better, I'm not sure what the issue is then. If you said it worked before making it a class, I'm guessing something somewhere is nil or a reference is being dropped. Use the debugger and run through it and make sure nothing is nil or incorrect

Comment: Okay i will do it right away, thank you for your concern.

Comment: You guessed well i have some chinese characters in my url :8. I will try to make them disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussion in comments it was identified the issue was URL encoding.

Check out this question / answer which will show you how to URLEncode a string:

[How do I URL encode a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088473/url-encode-an-nsstring)