# Convert Arabic NSString to Decode string in IOS

Tags: ios, nsstring

How to convert the Arabic text like `http://www.someurl.com/Category/صفوف` to `http://www.someurl.com/Category/%D8%B5%D9%81%D9%88%D9%81` , Like when we paste the `http://www.someurl.com/Category/صفوف` to any browser it will show `http://www.someurl.com/Category/%D8%B5%D9%81%D9%88%D9%81`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

many solutions available
try this page first solution and solution no (17) they've what you're looking 4

[How do I URL encode a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088473/url-encode-an-nsstring)