# What is the iOS proper URL encoding of "+" character?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Is there seriously not a way natively to URL Encode the value of a query string parameter that has a "+" character in it?

e.g.

`me+blah@domain.net`

to

`me%2Bblah%40@domain.net`?

I tried solutions like posted in these other questions, but those do not properly encode that email.

[Swift - encode URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551816/swift-encode-url/24552028#24552028)

[How do I URL encode a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088473/url-encode-an-nsstring)

A swift solution would be preferred as that is what I am working in at the moment, but I am capable of translating Objective-C Code to swift code for the most part.

Specifically I am trying to `x-www-form-urlencoded` encode query string values in the body of POST request.

Comment: Specify how the string/URL currently *is* being encoded (including at what steps such is applied) as context is very important to when `+` should, shouldn't, and might be percent encoded. The "proper encoding" is defined by these rules, outside (and long before) iOS.

Comment: @user2864740 I'm not sure I understand, I gave an example of input, and desired output. Currently the "+" character does not get encoded with any of the solutions provided on the other stackoverflow questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let email = "me+blah@domain.net"

let output = CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(nil, email as NSString, nil, ":/?@!$&'()*+,;=" as NSString, CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding))

// output = "me%2Bblah%40domain.net"
```

`CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` doesn't escape `+` or `@` by default, but you can specify it (as I did along with other characters, in the `":/?@!$&'()*+,;="` string).

---

**Edit:** If you want `output` to be a Swift string:

```
let output = (CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(nil, email as NSString, nil, ":/?@!$&'()*+,;=" as NSString, CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)) as NSString) as String
```

Comment: (I'm assuming you meant `me%2Bblah%40domain.net` as your desired output, and not `me%2blah%40@domain.net` as you actually typed.)

Comment: You are correct, I had a typo, fixed now. I will try this out.

Comment: Hmm this returns a `CFString`, which apparently does not want to be coaxed into a Swift `String` since `CFString` is not a `NSString`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```swift
println(("me+blah@domain.net" as NSString)
    .stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(
        NSCharacterSet.alphanumericCharacterSet()))
```

Output:

```swift
Optional("me%2Bblah%40domain%2Enet")
```

In Objective-C:

```objc
NSString *encodedString =
    ["me+blah@domain.net" stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:
        [NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet]];
```

Comment: But periods should not be encoded when the content type is `x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: You can add more characters to the character set, but is it really worth it?  The periods will be decoded properly.  You are **allowed** to encode more characters than you are **required** to encode.