# Why is my single quotation mark (') not getting encoded?

Tags: php, ios, mysql, objective-c, encoding

I have the following code to convert my **UITextView** text into an encoded **NSString** that I can insert into my database along with other stuff. The insert works perfectly fine except when there is a single quotation mark... then it doesn't work. When I **NSLog** the encoded **NSString**, the ' was not even converted into anything. So when it goes to do the web server request the url has the ' still in it which is causing it to fail... Why is the single quotation marks not getting encoded priorly? Here is my code (also I am not very good with php):

**iOS:**

```
NSString *encodedString = (NSString 
*)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
  NULL, (CFStringRef)self.textView.text,     NULL,  (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",      kCFStringEncodingUTF8 ));          
  NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://example.org/postText.php?thePost=%@&byUserID=%@&nickname=%@", encodedString, [UniqueUserIdentification getUserID], nickname];
```

**php:**

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("editout","editout","editout","editout");    
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$thePost = $_GET["thePost"];
$byUserID = $_GET["byUserID"];
$nickname = $_GET["nickname"];

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO MyTable
VALUES ('$thePost', '$byUserID', '$nickname', 0, 0)");    
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: Instead of doing validation from the iOS app, why not move it to the PHP? You should be preparing/executing the query too.

Comment: look at [**mysqli real escape string**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

Comment: Tried adding this after my GET and it still does't work: $thePost = $mysqli->real_escape_string($thePost);

Comment: I got it. Thank you! Turns out I wasn't properly updating the php script so it wasn't even recognizing the new script XD

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL is wrong.

```
$thePost = $_GET["thePost"];
```

You assign `$thePost` with the GET data, but that is url decoded.

For example, `$thePost` is "`Let's go!`", so your SQL becomes:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable
VALUES ('Let's go', '$byUserID', '$nickname', 0, 0)"
```

Obviously there is a syntax error.

You need to escape the string with [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).

And have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088473/url-encode-an-nsstring).

Answer (score -1):

in client , it code ' to %27, it is correct. But in the server, your sql use wrong.[urlencode](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

Comment: urlencode is applicable only for url. for other fields, it will make a messed up situation. parametrized query is the way to go. url isn't the only field he is inserting.

Comment: do you see his code, he encodes parameters too.Use the encode result to post to server.The server codes are wrong.

Comment: ^and he is getting the error in the server. what does that tell ya?

Comment: ' in sql ,it has some meaning that represents a string quote.So the server can get value,but the code : mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO MyTable
VALUES ('$thePost', '$byUserID', '$nickname', 0, 0)");  is wrong.

Comment: print that sql , it may like this INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES(''fdsaf','32','fdsa',0,0) , it has multiply ' in the values ,so the database will say wrong.It should escape the ' in the sql string.

Comment: exactly my point. the sql is right. he is just not escaping the strings. in DB, you escape quotes by parameterizing the query, not by urlencode.

Comment: This is server wrong at last.Server should use prepare sql to insert data.The client is right,escape the url paramter