# Strings with spaces failed to convert as NSURLs - Mantle

Tags: ios, github-mantle

Would like to know is there anyway that we could fix failing converting a string with space to NSURL in Mantle?

I'm getting below Mantle error:

Error Domain=MTLTransformerErrorHandlingErrorDomain Code=1 "Could not convert string to URL" UserInfo=0x7ff9e8de4090 {MTLTransformerErrorHandlingInputValueErrorKey=https://x.com/dev-pub-image-md/x-img/02020-x yy z@2X.png, NSLocalizedDescription=Could not convert string to URL, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Input URL string https://x.com/dev-pub-image-md/x-img/02020-x yy z@2X.png was malformed}

Below the class files;

.h -

```
#import "Mantle.h"

@interface Place : MTLModel <MTLJSONSerializing>

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *placeId;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSURL *logoURL;

@end
```

.m -

```
#import "Place.h"

@implementation Place

+ (NSDictionary *)JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey {
    return @{@"placeId": @"placeId",
             @"logoURL":@"circleImage"
             };
}

+ (NSValueTransformer *)logoURLJSONTransformer {
    return [NSValueTransformer valueTransformerForName:MTLURLValueTransformerName];
}

@end
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

This happens because your string is not URL endcoded (URLs cannot have spaces).

First - URL encode your string using the following method. Source : [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088473/how-do-i-url-encode-a-string)

```
- (NSString *)urlencodeString:(NSString*)string {
    NSMutableString *output = [NSMutableString string];
    const unsigned char *source = (const unsigned char *)[self UTF8String];
    int sourceLen = strlen((const char *)source);
    for (int i = 0; i < sourceLen; ++i) {
        const unsigned char thisChar = source[i];
        if (thisChar == ' '){
            [output appendString:@"+"];
        } else if (thisChar == '.' || thisChar == '-' || thisChar == '_' || thisChar == '~' || 
                   (thisChar >= 'a' && thisChar <= 'z') ||
                   (thisChar >= 'A' && thisChar <= 'Z') ||
                   (thisChar >= '0' && thisChar <= '9')) {
            [output appendFormat:@"%c", thisChar];
        } else {
            [output appendFormat:@"%%%02X", thisChar];
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

And then convert it to a URL.

In your specific scenario, you're working with Mantle JSON transformers. So what you can do is;

```
+ (NSValueTransformer *)logoURLJSONTransformer {
    return [MTLValueTransformer transformerUsingReversibleBlock:^id(NSString *str, BOOL *success, NSError *__autoreleasing *error) {
        if (success) {
            NSString *urlEncodedString  = [self urlencodeString:str];
            return [NSURL URLWithString:urlEncodedString];
        }else{
            return @"";
        }

    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
NSString *baseurlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"your_url_here"];
NSString *cleanedUrl = [baseurlString stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet]];
```

then use this `cleanedUrl` for your work.