# Objective - C stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters not working

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a URL like so ANC & SHO.pdf

when I encode the URL like so:

```
NSString *escapedString = [PDFPath stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]];
```

now when I use this URL it does not work and I have a feeling it has to do with the & because when I tried another file, it worked perfectly I was able to load the PDF, but with the file with & I was not.

What Am I doing wrong?

Here is the output of escapedString

```
escapedString   __NSCFString *  @"Ancaster%5CANC%20&%20SHO%20-%20Laundry%20Closets%20to%20be%20Checked.pdf" 0x16ea33c0
```

I then use that to call a method:

```
NSArray *byteArray = [dataSource.areaData GetPDFFileData:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",escapedString]];
```

Here is the method:

```
-(NSArray *)GetPDFFileData:(NSString *)PDFFile
{
    NSString *FileBrowserRequestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?PDFFile=%@",kIP,PDFFile];
    NSURL *JSONURL = [NSURL URLWithString:FileBrowserRequestString];
    NSURLResponse* response = nil;
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:JSONURL];
    NSData* data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];
    if(data == nil)
        return nil;
    NSError *myError;
    NSArray *tableArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&myError]];
    return tableArray;
}
```

Comment: Show the contents of `escapedString`.

Comment: escapedString __NSCFString * @"Ancaster%5CANC%20&%20SHO%20-%20Laundry%20Closets%20to%20be%20Checked.pdf" 0x16ea33c0

Comment: That looks OK.  How are you using the string to fetch the file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I URL encode a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088473/how-do-i-url-encode-a-string)

Comment: you are using different method, you need to add escape characters into your string, use `[@"Your URL string" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`[NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]` contains characters below:

```
!$&'()*+,-.0123456789:;=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[]_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz~
```

which contains '`&`', so

```
NSString *escapedString = [PDFPath stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]];
```

won't escape '&' for you, then it's not URLEncoded.

see the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088473/how-do-i-url-encode-a-string) about how to url encode a string.