# How to send string using ASCII value in objective c to the server

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, ascii

I need a help ....I am trying to send the string like `<ABCs>` to the server but its showing error due to `<>` can any one tell me how do i send this string to server ASCII value for `<>` and my `ABCs` string as well ??? so the my final string is `<ABCs>`

Comment: i want to send final string <ABCs>

Comment: You need to edit the actual post and clean it up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure that problem is in "<>" characters, then you should encode string on one side, and then decode it on another.

See answers in here "[How do I URL encode a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088473/how-do-i-url-encode-a-string)" to learn how to urlencode string in iOS.

If you will have this problem anyway, please show the way you are communicating with server.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response your way is also good but i did simple using "stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString" i replace the string .........and it worked ....