# Getting JSON data using NSURLSession

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json, nsurlsession

Im trying to get Data from google distance api using NSURLSession  but as seen below in code when i print response and data, i get the results as NULL.
What can be the issue? or is there any other better way of fetching JSON data.

```
NSString *urlAsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Vancouver+BC|Seattle&destinations=San+Francisco|Victoria+BC&mode=bicycling&language=fr-FR&key=API-KEY"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAsString];


NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

[[session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlAsString]
            completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

                NSLog(@"RESPONSE: %@",response);
                NSLog(@"DATA: %@",data);


            }] resume];
```

Comment: why are you using `stringWithFormat`?

Comment: You may want to edit out your api key to protect yourself from service abuse.

Comment: You don't need that standalone "`NSURL *url =`" line up there.  You don't use it.

Comment: I think the issue is with URL

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` on your url string, this is why you didn't get a response : the server returned an error.

You should have checked the `error` ;)

I replaced your API key in URL string, remember to put your own if you copy/paste my code :)

```
NSString *urlAsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Vancouver+BC|Seattle&destinations=San+Francisco|Victoria+BC&mode=bicycling&language=fr-FR&key=YOUR-API-KEY"];

NSCharacterSet *set = [NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet];
NSString *encodedUrlAsString = [urlAsString stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:set];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

[[session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:encodedUrlAsString]
        completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"RESPONSE: %@",response);
    NSLog(@"DATA: %@",data);

    if (!error) {
        // Success
        if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]]) {
            NSError *jsonError;
            NSDictionary *jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&jsonError];

            if (jsonError) {
                // Error Parsing JSON

            } else {
                // Success Parsing JSON
                // Log NSDictionary response:
                NSLog(@"%@",jsonResponse);
            }
        }  else {
            //Web server is returning an error
        }
    } else {
        // Fail
        NSLog(@"error : %@", error.description);
    }
}] resume];
```

Comment: thanks! encoding has worked..but the way you have encoded is deprecated iOS 9 onwards.

Answer (score 3):

You might get a really good hint if you print out what's returned in the error parameter.

I.E.:

```
NSString *unencodedURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Vancouver+BC|Seattle&destinations=San+Francisco|Victoria+BC&mode=bicycling&language=fr-FR&key=API-KEY"];
NSString *encodedURLString = (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
                        NULL,
                        (CFStringRef)unencodedURLString,
                        NULL,
                        (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
                        kCFStringEncodingUTF8 );

[[session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:encodedURLString]
            completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

    if (error != nil)
    {
       // if there's an error, print it out...
       NSLog(@"error in NSURLSession is %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    } else {
       NSLog(@"RESPONSE: %@",response);
       NSLog(@"DATA: %@",data);
    }
}] resume];
```

The URL encoding routine I'm using [is found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088473/how-do-i-url-encode-a-string).

Comment: its says unsupported URL.but if i run the same url on browser i see the json data.

Comment: @Rusty well, there you have it.

Comment: @njzk2 i didn't understand.

Comment: yeah i understood that ..but if the url is giving me json in browser it means that my url is correct. @njzk2
what can be the issue with the format any idea?

Comment: It probably has to do with URL encoding your parameters

Answer (score 0):

**From the Documentation:**

The url must be in the format:

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Vancouver+BC|Seattle&destinations=San+Francisco|Victoria+BC&key=YOUR_API_KEY

You are requesting:

```
origins: Vancouver+BC|Seattle
destinations: San+Francisco|Victoria+BC
mode: driving
key: API_KEY
```

For Transit:

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Vancouver+BC|Seattle&destinations=San+Francisco|Victoria+BC&mode=transit&transit_mode=train&key=YOUR_API_KEY

You are requesitn:

```
  origins: Vancouver+BC|Seattle
destinations: San+Francisco|Victoria+BC
mode: transit
transit_mode: train
key: API_KEY
```

Comment: i have the same url ..still it says unsupported url

Comment: try removing the language tag you have in your url

Comment: im not sure if API key have dashes in it. Also check if your api key is correct or not.

Comment: did you check the link in the POSTMan plugin in chrome ? See if you get any json data in there

Comment: How can we pass longitude and latitude in Google Distance Matrix API request ?
If i have retrieved a place using Google Places how to pass the place to Google Distance Matrix API?
@Mr.T

Comment: there is parameter called origins, and you can send coordinates like: origins=Bobcaygeon+ON|41.43206,-81.38992