# Passing long strings from iOS to MySQL Database

Tags: php, ios, mysql

I am able to post from my iOS app to my MySQL database but when I have long sentences for example

I am trying to post this string: `"Hello, how are you today?"`

It won't do anything. So I improvised and replaced the spaces with `_` and my string would look like this `"Hello,_how_are_you_today?"` and
that worked!

But I thought it's weird that I have to do that.

So my question is, how can I post long strings with spaces without modifying it like how I did?

Here is the code that I have

iOS

```
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.example.com/post.php?dishname=%@&description=%@, dishname.text, description.text]";
    NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
    NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", strResult);
```

php code

```
<?php

// Create connection
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "admin";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "dbname";
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","admin","root","dbname");

if (!$con) {
 die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
 echo "Nothing happened";

}else{


}


if (isset ($_GET["dishname"]))
        $dishname = $_GET["dishname"];

    else
        $dishname = "Null";
if (isset ($_GET["description"]))
        $description = $_GET["description"];
    else
        $description = "Null";

echo "dishname : ". $dishname;
echo "description : ". $description;

$sql = "insert into RecipeFeed (DishName, Description) values ('".$dishname."','".$description."')";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$GET` or `$_POST` data directly into a query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is a URL allowed to contain a space?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497908/is-a-url-allowed-to-contain-a-space)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something that's already been thought over. Don't reinvent the wheel. If you'd like to continue to use GET, use [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088473/how-do-i-url-encode-a-string) for handling encoding on the iOS side, and read about [this PHP method](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) for the PHP side. **OR**, you can use POST (which actually fits this better), and you don't have to encode anything.

I don't really think this needs a code example, and I'm not writing the iOS side (because it's in the link), but the PHP side should look like:

```
$dishname = isset($_POST["dishname"]) ? $_POST["dishname"] : null;
$description = isset($_POST["description"]) ? $_POST["description"] : null;

// do inserts per @tadman's answer
```

If you need to use GET for whatever reason,

```
$dishname = isset($_GET["dishname"]) ? urldecode($_GET["dishname"]) : null;
$description = isset($_GET["description"]) ? urldecode($_GET["description"]) : null;
```

Comment: Oh, it is now. I was commenting on a much earlier edit apparently.

Comment: @tadman I know I added code per your comment, but I don't really think that it needed any.

Answer (score 2):

It's a lot cleaner to code if you use the object-oriented interface:

```
$con = new mysqli("localhost","admin","root","dbname");

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
  die("Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error);
  // Note, nothing happens after die inside the same block, so
  // don't put code here. It will never, ever run.
}
```

You also have a lot of dead code there that does nothing that's been removed.

Using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) makes your statements easy to read and keeps you safe from SQL injection problems if you're careful not to use string interpolation:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO RecipeFeed (DishName, Description) VALUES (?, ?)");

$stmt->bind_param('ss', $_GET['description'], $_GET['dishname']);

$result = $stmt->execute();
```

This will handle all your quoting for you, and as a bonus you don't have to worry about them being set or not.