# unable to decode HTML string

Tags: html, ios, objective-c

I have to decode a HTML string, but the response is not coming well. This is my URL from where I have to decode my HTML string: [`http://www.delvetech.org/sharpkirana/sharpapi/aboutApi.php`](http://www.delvetech.org/sharpkirana/sharpapi/aboutApi.php).

My code is given below:

```cc
NSString *HTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html>\n"
                  "<head>\n"
                  "<style type=\"text/css\">\n"
                  "body {font-family: \"%@\"; font-size: %@; color:#%@;}\n"
                  "</style>\n"
                  "</head>\n"
                  "<body>%@</body>\n"
                  "</html>",
                  font.familyName, @(font.pointSize), colorHexString, htmlBodyString];
return HTML;
```

Is there a problem in my code or are the HTML strings wrong?

Comment: Helpful link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088473/how-do-i-url-encode-a-string

Comment: What's the method that you use to parse the api's response?  Which means how to get the **htmlBodyString**?

Comment: @EricXuan sir this is my method-NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.delvetech.org/sharpkirana/sharpapi/termNconditionApi.php?description=%@",[self.textUrl stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"]];
  
    
    [DownloadManager getData:url withBlock:^(NSData *receivedData, NSURLResponse *responce, NSError *error)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSAttributedString *HTML=[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[HTMLCodeString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUTF8StringEncoding]} documentAttributes:nil error:nil];

retutn HTML;
```

Comment: sir this code not solved my problem...actually i"m new in iOS so plz tell me something in detail...plz sir