# Escaping ampersand in iOS Wikipedia app

Tags: ios, escaping, wikipedia, url-encoding, ampersand

From within my iOS app these open the correct page (for the film "&ME") via openURL:

`wikipedia://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/&ME`
`https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/&ME`
`https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=%26ME`

But these don't (they open some other, i.e. error, page):

`wikipedia://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=&ME`
`wikipedia://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=%26ME`
`wikipedia://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=%2526ME`
`wikipedia://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=%25%26ME`

Searches not containing '&' work fine.

If you've solved this, what did you do?
Or can you suggest another way to escape ampersand I haven't tried?
Or does this look like a bug in the iOS Wikipedia app?

Comment: This may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8088484/4797324

Comment: Thanks, but that discussion addresses how to obtain %26; my problem is that %26 doesn't work in one case (iOS Wikipedia app search), but works in all other cases (iOS Wikipedia app link, iOS Google and IMDb apps). I also tried "&amp" and "%26amp" (I'll try anything!) with no luck.

Comment: & symbol separates different parameters. So 'search=&ME' means parameter 'search' with empty value and one more incomplete parameter 'ME'.

Comment: Thanks again, but I do know what *doesn't* work!  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It was an iOS Wikipedia app bug, will be fixed in rev 5.6.0