# URL Encoding of String accepting all special characters in swift

Tags: ios, swift, urlencode

Trying to encode string added with special characters with below code:

```
let encodedString = myString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)
```

which does not include all special characters.

Also tried below options:

- .urlHostAllowed
- .urlFragmentAllowed
- .urlPasswordAllowed
- .urlPathAllowed
- .urlUserAllowed
- .urlQueryAllowed

but it's not working.

Please tell me if there is any other approach for URL encoding to include all special characters.

**Edit**

Adding `:` as input in string it converts to `%3A`. Same way for `@` - `%40`.

But adding `&` remains same. Required output is `%26`.

Comment: Please include the actual String you are trying to encode with the expected encoded result and the actual result.

Comment: *"which does not include all special characters."* - what are you trying to achieve? What is the input, actual output and expected output?

Comment: edit question with your url

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/a/45871217 should be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you @MartinR and @benleggiero for : [How do I URL encode a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088473/how-do-i-url-encode-a-string/45871217#45871217)

It helped a lot.

It was not including all special characters.

Checked one by one and added those which were missing as below:

```
extension CharacterSet {

    public static let urlQueryParameterAllowed = CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed.subtracting(CharacterSet(charactersIn: "&?~!$*(.,)_-+':"))

    public static let urlQueryDenied           = CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed.inverted()
    public static let urlQueryKeyValueDenied   = CharacterSet.urlQueryParameterAllowed.inverted()
    public static let urlPathDenied            = CharacterSet.urlPathAllowed.inverted()
    public static let urlFragmentDenied        = CharacterSet.urlFragmentAllowed.inverted()
    public static let urlHostDenied            = CharacterSet.urlHostAllowed.inverted()

    public static let urlDenied                = CharacterSet.urlQueryDenied
        .union(.urlQueryKeyValueDenied)
        .union(.urlPathDenied)
        .union(.urlFragmentDenied)
        .union(.urlHostDenied)


    public func inverted() -> CharacterSet {
        var copy = self
        copy.invert()
        return copy
    }
}
```