# Why NSXMLDocument doesn't escape newline character (\n)

Tags: objective-c, xml, cocoa

I'm running this code:

```
NSXMLElement *element = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"name" stringValue:@"value\n"];
NSXMLDocument *document = [[NSXMLDocument alloc] initWithRootElement:element];
NSLog(@"%@", document.XMLString);
```

And I'm getting this result:

```
<name>value
</name>
```

But I'm expecting the result to be:

```
<name>value&#xA;</name>
```

Does anybody know why `NSXMLDocument` doesn't escape `\n`? Is it an expected behavior?

I also tried `XMLStringWithOptions:` with different options, e.g. `NSXMLNodePreserveWhitespace`, but with no luck.

Answer (score 2):

Because `\n` is valid xml.  If you really want values to be URL encoded, you'll need to encode them.

[How do I URL encode a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088473/how-do-i-url-encode-a-string/8088484)

Comment: What about attribute values? I believe that `\n` in attribute values must be escaped.

Comment: Pretty sure the same goes for attribute values

Comment: It seems no. According to the doc https://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-xml-c14n-20000119.html#charescaping it must be escaped for XML version 1.0